# AS3: Can we skip an optional parameter and assign value to the parameter after the skipped one?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, parameters, overloading

Can we skip an optional parameter and assign value to the parameter after the skipped one?

For example I have a function:

```
public function Dialog(message:String,title:String="Note",dialogsize:int=99):void
{
}
```

I can easily call the function with a message and a title:

```
 Dialog("HELLO","Intro");
```

Is there a way to skip the title and just pass in the dialogsize? I've tried it but can't make it work:

```
Dialog("HELLO",,dialogsize);
```

Is it possible to skip some optional parameters without using (rest) parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `null`, for a "defaulted" parameter, and as3 will use the default value -- same as if you had omitted it completely:

```
Dialog("HELLO",null,dialogsize);
```

---

**Edit**

I stand corrected -- I could swear that I've done this before, with success... but my tests (and those of @www0z0k also) indicate otherwise.  That means that, in order to have the above work as described, you'd need to modify the function's implementation too.

Something like this will do the trick:

```
public function Dialog(message:String,title:String=null,dialogsize:int=99):void
{
    if(title===null) title = "Note";

}
```

Comment: well, it's not impossible but it's useless: i define `public function Dialog(message:String, title:String = "Note", dialogsize:int = 99):void { trace('message = ' + message + ', title = ' + title + ', dialogsize = ' + dialogsize); }`, then call `Dialog('msg', null, 250);` and trace is `message = msg, title = null, dialogsize = 250`. So passing `null` won't cause an argument be its' default value

Comment: @www0z0k - I stand corrected.  (I could swear that I've done this as I described, but my tests just showed the same thing you reported).  I've modified my answer to reflect something that *will* work.

Comment: Thank You all, I will accept that it is not possible to do it with just the parameters, the solution is to put some logic in the function to handle the arguments sent Or use a different approach such as valued object.

Comment: It should also be noted that passing null won't work all that well with the simple types like Number, Boolean and such. There's likely some conversion made in those cases instead of a null value being passed. Also, there's a shorthand for checking for null: title = title || "Note". Do note that the aforementioned caveat about simple types apply for the shorthand as well.

Answer (score 2):

it's impossible, but you can do something like:

```
public function Dialog(message:String, optionalArgs: Object):void{
    var title: String = optionalArgs['title'] ? optionalArgs['title'] : 'default value';
    var dialogsize: int =  optionalArgs['dialogsize'] ? optionalArgs['dialogsize'] : 99;
    var smthElse: String =  optionalArgs['smthElse'] ? optionalArgs['smthElse'] : 'another default val';
}
```

and:
`Dialog('msg', {dialogsize: 250, smthElse: 'another value'});`

Comment: it is not impossible (see my answer for details).

Comment: @ Lee : passing `null` would just set an argument you want to keep at default value to `null`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a **valued object** instead of an object to have more control over the contents:

```
// DialogVO.as
package
{
    public class DialogVO
    {
        public var message : String;
        public var title : String;
        public var size : int;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Test.as
public function createDialog(vo : DialogVO) : void
{
    if(vo.title)
        // write code for title here

    if(vo.message)
        // write code for meassage here

    if(vo.size)
        // write code for size here
}
```

---

```
// test your method
var dialogData : DialogVO = new DialogVO();
    dialogData.message = "This is the message";
    dialogData.size = 92;

createDialog(dialogData);
```

Comment: It's typically preferable to set those values in the constructor *(so we can make the object immutable)*, but then we run into the same optional-parameters problem...